# Best way to submit UL via POST?

Tags: php, jquery

Quick question...

I have an input box that upon key enter, adds the value to an unordered list. How would I pass this unordered list to jquery post? I'm using the form.serialize, so I don't have to define each variable for posting.

Example, let's say I entered 3 fruits and they get dynamically added to an unordered list inside the form.

> Fruit: [input text here]
>
> - Apple
> - Banana
> - Pear

I was thinking of creating a hidden text field that would populate with the new value everytime the user pressed enter.

Any other thoughts?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
<ul>
    <li>Apple<input type='hidden' name='fruits[]' value='Apple'/></li>
    <li>Pear<input type='hidden' name='fruits[]' value='Pear'/></li>
    <li>Banana<input type='hidden' name='fruits[]' value='Banana'/></li>
</ul>
```

When submitted, you'll get an array in `$_POST` named `fruits` with those value.

Comment: Just what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

Something like that (dynamic construction of the ul content):

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>S.O. 3287336</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#add').click(function() {
            var li = $('<li></li>').text($('#edit').val());
            $('#ul').append(li);
        });

        $('#addForm').submit(function() {
            var ul = "";

            $('#ul li').each(function() {
                ul += $(this).html() + ";"
            });

            alert("About to submit: " + ul); 
            return false; // don't submit
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<ul id="ul">
</ul>
<form id="addForm">
    <input type="text" name="edit" id="edit" value=""/>
    <input type="button" id="add" value="Add"/>
    <input type="submit" id="submit-btn" value="End"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

when you add thing dynamically to your UL you can add hidden inputs with array name like

```
<input type='hidden' name='ul[1]' value='banana'/>
<input type='hidden' name='ul[2]' value='apple'/>
<input type='hidden' name='ul[3]' value='pear'/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something similar works with Pythons Flask, but you have to use request.form.getlist(arg) instead of just "get".

In fruits.html:

```
<form action='/test' method="post">
    <ul>
        <li>Apple<input type='hidden' name='fruits' value='Apple'/></li>
        <li>Pear<input type='hidden' name='fruits' value='Pear'/></li>
        <li>Banana<input type='hidden' name='fruits' value='Banana'/></li>
    </ul>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

In app.py:

```
@app.route('/fruits', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def get_fruits():
if request.method == 'POST':
    fruits = request.form.getlist("fruits")
    print fruits
return render_template(fruits.html)
```

This will print out:

```
['Apple', 'Pear', 'Banana']
```