# How to do options with suboptions?

Tags: php, html, html-select, selection

I would like create a select that have options and suboptions.

For example, if I have a form similar like this one:

```
<form method="post" action="processor.php">
  <select name="mySelect">
    <option value="1">Parent option 1</option>
      <option value="1">Child option 1 of parent 1</option>
      <option value="2">Child option 2 of parent 1</option>
      <option value="3">Child option 3 of parent 1</option>
    <option value="2">Parent option 1</option>
      <option value="1">Child option 1 of parent 2</option>
      <option value="2">Child option 2 of parent 2</option>
      <option value="3">Child option 3 of parent 2</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

I would like when the user select the `Parent 1` option, I receive a array like this one:

```
array(
    "parent" => "1"
);
```

And when selecting the `Child option 3 of parent 2` option, I receive a array like:

```
array(
    "parent" => "2"
    "child"  => "3"
);
```

How can I perform this? I can send something like `parent_2|child_3` and explode, but I think this isn't the best way.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/optgroup

Answer (score 3):

The `<select>` tag does not support nested options. It supports [groups](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/optgroup), but not a real hierarchy.

There are available JavaScript-based replacements that use nested lists to perform the same type of functionality. You may wish to explore this option.

Answer (score 0):

try using "`<ul>`" tags instead of "`<select>`" then put some jquery or javascript and CSS to do the animation (hide, show) thing then on submit get selected value using javascript or do it like this:

[Best way to submit UL via POST?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3287336/best-way-to-submit-ul-via-post)

cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I think you would benefit far more from a javascript-based tree control rather than a selector. You could have infinite levels of hierarchy and the selection mechanism would be pretty much what you're looking for.

Have you given a look at, for example, [DHTMLX Tree](http://www.dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxTree/)?