# innerHTML name and value

Tags: javascript, php

I was wondering how can I add a `value` and a `name` for each of `li` elements created via `innerHTML`. My original ul is empty and every time the user clicks on the `button` the input is stored in a new `li` item. I would like to add two things in that innerHTML:

- A `name`, the same for one for every new `li`: `indiv-keywords`
- A `value`, which is the value entered by the user

[image]

```
const generateTemplate = (word, location) => {
 const html = `
    <li><span>${word}</span>
    <i class="far fa-times-circle delete"></i>
    </li>
 `;
 console.log(html);

 numberKeywords = numberKeywords + 1;
 location.innerHTML += html;
};
```

What I would like to get from that list is that:

```
<ul>
    <li>${word}<input type='hidden' name='fruits[]' value='Apple'/></li>
    <li>${word}<input type='hidden' name='fruits[]' value='Pear'/></li>
    <li>${word}<input type='hidden' name='fruits[]' value='Banana'/></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please go read [ask]. You are expected to tell us what the actual _problem_ is, not _just_ what you “want”. (And FYI, LI elements in HTML do not have a name or a value attribute - if that’s what you actually meant. You _can_ add them, but the won’t have any functionality on their own. And if you want to add additional functionality, some sort of scripting or whatever, you should rather use custom data attributes to begin with.)

Comment: Your post can be read again infinity times, that doesn’t change the fact that it does not currently contain an actual problem description.

Comment: @Laura1999 What is your problem with the code you already have? Adding the name attribute to the li is a trivial task after you have created what you already have.

Comment: 1) You are expected to tell us what the actual problem --> I think I did spefify what was the actual problem

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3287336/best-way-to-submit-ul-via-post this is something like in the first answer of that post I am trying to achieve

Comment: Teemu, I am just trying to add a name for each li generated and a value so I can submit every li value with POST on PHP

Comment: OK, now we know. That's not possible, `name` attribute is native (and has native behavior) only with form control and window elements. What you need, is to set  hidden inputs to your form, and populate their values with the values of the LIs.

Comment: Thank you for giving me some hints.

Answer (score 0):

If the generatedTemplate is a function then something like this should work:

```
const generateTemplate = (word, name, inputvalue, location) => {
 const html = `
    <li data-name="${name}" data-value="${inputvalue}"><span>${word}</span>
    <i class="far fa-times-circle delete"></i>
    </li>
 `;
 console.log(html);

 numberKeywords = numberKeywords + 1;
 location.innerHTML += html;
};
```

All depends on the way how the generateTemplate is being used.

Comment: I can't accept it because I need more SO credits :(